# How can I understand amplifier types?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, frequency-response

I am studying for my final exam.

I am struggling a bit with the frequency response formulas. For instance like this circuit, the formulas generally are the same.  I don't know what type amplifier it is:

[image]

On the other hand, the answer says that this circuit it is cascode amplifier, and the formulas are completely different. How can I understand if it is cascode or not, or if it is it CC-CE, CC-CB etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the CE, CC, CB nomenclature is which pin is common to both input and output.

In the first schematic note that the emitter is connected to ground, so is one terminal of the input signal and the output load so it is a common emitter amplifier.

Any capacitors in the path are assumed to be a short circuit at AC. If for example there was an emitter resistor that was bypassed with a capacitor it would still be a common emitter amplifier.

It is not a cascode that you correctly show in the second diagram.

Be careful of the distinction between cascode and cascade (letter 'a' in word). A cascade just means two amplifiers in succession rather than a specific circuit configuration.

Answer (score 2):

A casc**o**de is a "stack" of two or more transistors, with at least *one* of them in common base configuration. In your figure (b), Q2 is operating common base and provides a stable collector voltage for Q1, while passing Q1's collector current mostly unaltered.